# How to use arguments of to_factor in tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to convert variables `a` and `b` into factors, but I want to use two arguments of `to_factor` namely `drop_unused_labels` and `ordered`. But I receive an error when I try to use them in the context of `mutate_at`. Is there an alternative syntax to use it?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(labelled)
df <- data.frame(
  a = labelled(c(1, 1, 2, 3), labels = c(No = 1, Yes = 2)),
  b = labelled(c(1, 1, 2, 3), labels = c(No = 1, Yes = 2, DK = 3))
)

# converting vars a and b to factor

glimpse(df %>% mutate_at(vars(a:b), to_factor))
#> Rows: 4
#> Columns: 2
#> $ a <fct> No, No, Yes, 3
#> $ b <fct> No, No, Yes, DK

# But I want to use two arguments of to_factor
glimpse(df %>% mutate_at(vars(a:b), 
                          to_factor(drop_unused_labels=TRUE, ordered=TRUE)))
#> Error in var_label(x): argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters can be passed as arguments after the function.

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(a:b), 
    to_factor,
    drop_unused_labels = TRUE,
    ordered = TRUE
  )
```

Alternatively, you can specify the function

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(a:b), 
    function(x) to_factor(x, drop_unused_labels = TRUE, ordered = TRUE)
  )
```

Or equivalently

```
df %>%
  mutate_at(
    vars(a:b), 
    ~to_factor(., drop_unused_labels = TRUE, ordered = TRUE)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `mutate` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(across(a:b, ~ to_factor(.x, drop_unused_labels = TRUE, ordered = TRUE)))
```